# Use Eloquent Model with more than one methods

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Suppose  I have a Model called `ManageUser.`
I have three methods.   `public static function registerusr(), public static function updateuser() and  public static function removeuser().` 
In my UserController  i called them like

`$data=ManageUser::registeruser()
$data=ManageUser::updateuser()
$data=ManageUser::removeuser()`

This is the fluent way to call the models methods.I am bit confused about Eloquent relationship over normal fluent query.I understand that its optimized the queries.
If i use Eloquent relationship how can i call the different methods in controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relationships inside any of your model methods. Just an example:

```
public static function updateUser($user, $roles)
{
    $user->update(['status' => 1]);
    return $user->roles()->sync($roles);
}
```

And call the method as you call it now:

```
ManageUser::updateUser($user, $roles);
```